# How send mutipart/form-data request with curl

Tags: curl, timeout, multipart

I am trying to send a multipart form request thru curl but it seems to be timing out on the server. I am not a curl wiz and am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I can post thru postman just fine and if I copy the curl request out of postman and tweak to escape the / and ' characters, it seems like it should work and looking at the logs the requests coming from both look pretty dang close so I must be missing something obvious. Here is my request:

```
curl -v -X POST ^
  http://localhost:8096/api/sys/cfna-notifications/v1/email-notifications ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" ^
  -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Content-Length: 977" ^
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" ^
  -H "Host: localhost:8096" ^
  -H "cache-control: no-cache" ^
  -H "client_id: mmmm" ^
  -H "client_secret: dddd" ^
  -H "content-type: multipart/form-data" ^
  -F transactionId=asdfd-213sdf-sdf4-2323kjds ^
  -F parentTransactionId=12345 ^
  -F businessProcess=test ^
  -F toAddresses=bogartlisa@cfna.com ^
  -F "subject=test this notification" ^
  -F "body=body of notification email"
```

maybe a stupid question but do I need to do something to terminate the final part of the multipart request???

Comment: tried the following and still times out

Comment: curl -v -X POST ^
  http://localhost:8096/api/sys/cfna-notifications/v1/email-notifications ^
  -H "Content-Length: 977" ^
  -H "Host: localhost:8096" ^
  -H "client_id: mmmm" ^
  -H "client_secret: dddd" ^
  -H "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" ^
  -F transactionId=asdfd-213sdf-sdf4-2323kjds ^
  -F parentTransactionId=12345 ^
  -F businessProcess=test ^
  -F toAddresses=bogartlisa@cfna.com ^
  -F "subject=test this notification" ^
  -F "body=body of notification email"

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't - curl knows how many parts you've specified and will "end" the series appropriately itself when sending the data.

(Bonus: remove the `-X POST`, that's just bad practice.)

It is very possible that one of your `-H` provided headers is screwing things up for curl. Remove all of them except the two for "client*" stuff and I think things might go better.